# Put legend outside of subplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

I have created a subplot figure with `multi_fig, multi_ax = plt.subplots(2, 2, sharex=True)`

I am later trying to set a legend outside the chart area, I have tried `multi_fig.legend(labels = energy_data["Fuel"].unique(), bbox_to_anchor=(1,1), loc="upper right")` but the legend still appears overlapped with the sub fig in position [0, 1].

Is it possible to have the legend outside of the subplot?

Comment: Make the location upper left.

Comment: @JodyKlymak that worked thanks. The legend is in the right location but it is extends beyond the size of the figure window

Comment: That’s true.  If you make it an axes legend and use constrained_layout it should make room for you.  Or you can use bbox_inches=‘tight’ when saving the figure.

Comment: Thanks. This was very useful:
https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/intermediate/constrainedlayout_guide.html